# Cannot find my hard disk while installing linux-“No root file system defined” error

Tags: linux, filesystems, installation

I am trying install Linux on my computer (tried Ubuntu 10.4 and Linux Mint 9).

I started the installation wizard and on the hard disk selection page the hard disk is not displayed. I have a 500GB disk with 5 partitions and windows 7 ultimate in one partition.
If I click the forward button, it shows an error- "**No root file system defined**".

I have tried to install by booting from CD and pendrive but both shows the same error.

When I load Linux as live CD it doesn't show the hard disk.

My hard disk works fine in windows 7.

System config:
intel i3 2100,
500GB hdd,
2GB ram

Answer (score 0):

Check from LiveCD with:

```
#fdisk -l
```

or start GParted.

P.S.:You should remember, that you cannot have more than 4 primary partitions with MBR.

see this link for details: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80455/no-root-file-system-defined-error-while-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: Actually you can, with the GUID (GPT) partitioning scheme. The limit of 4 partitions is specific to MBR.

Comment: i opened GParted from live cd ,but my hdd is not shown there.  I have 2 primary partition and 3 extended parttions

Answer (score 0):

This hard drive, is it an IDE (OLD) hard drive? If not, you might be running it in IDE (compatible) mode.

Solutions:

1. Upgrade your harddrive to a ATA one.
2. Disable compatibility-mode in BIOS.
3. Find a linux distribution with a kernel that supports IDE drives.

Comment: it is a SATA drive and it is not in compatibility-mode